# DialogFragment views created callback?

Tags: android

I have the following problem.
I'm creating and showing the `DialogFragment` which have WebView.
WebView have `onProgressChanged` callback.
When the `progress = 100 (loading finished)` I want to make
`Picture picture = webView.createPicture();` - snapshot of the view.

The problem is that I cant convert that Picture to bitmap (exception width must be >0).

I think that the problem is Webview is not currently displayed and it's `width = 0;`

Can you advice me some callback like "`onDialogShown`" or something?

Comment: code & logcat needed. normally, people here can see the error with these!

Comment: try adding a delay before doing the capturepicture so that the webview is shown.